# What is the use of Public Key in Android developer console?

Tags: android

I have signed my android application with keytool but don't know what to do with public key in my android developer console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/setting-up.html). It is a part of Android Application Licensing from Google